# register a protocol on mac osx?

Tags: macos, protocols

I have done it in windows, how do i register a protocol on mac osx. I want to click links in firefox (a href="somename://mylinkAndData") and launch a binary?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have a look at Apple's [Launch Services Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/LaunchServicesConcepts/LSCIntro/LSCIntro.html). You have to add *[CFBundleURLTypes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/cfbundleurltypes)* to your apps Info.plist and register your app with *LSRegisterURL()*.

Excerpt from *Firefox.app/Contents/Info.plist*:

```
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
            <dict>
                    <key>CFBundleURLIconFile</key>
                    <string>document.icns</string>
                    <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
                    <string>http URL</string>
                    <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
                    <array>
                            <string>http</string>
                    </array>
            </dict>
 ....
```

**EDIT:** See [Handling URL schemes in Cocoa](https://web.archive.org/web/20091215155410/http://www.xmldatabases.org/WK/blog/1154_Handling_URL_schemes_in_Cocoa.item) for a *how-to* article

Comment: A more recent How-To: https://css-tricks.com/create-url-scheme/