# External Protocol Handlers and Modern Browsers

Tags: macos, google-chrome, github

I've noticed that GitHub launched a new "Clone in Mac" button a couple of months ago, which - when clicked - perform an external protocol request:

```
github-mac://openRepo/REPOURL
```

Assuming I want to implement a similar feature for my application, I wonder:

- how do buttons degrade if the user browser doesn't support external protocols
- how to register the protocol handler without requiring user action. In other words, how do you tell browser X to use application GitHub.app in case of protocol github-mac, without asking the user to tweak the browser settings?
- I can see in the above URL an *openRepo* action, which inform the application about the action to perform. What are the common strategies/patterns to dispatch these requests for a Mac application, so that `github-mac://first` does something different from `github-mac://second`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Browsers differ in the way they handle new protocols.
Check documentation here where they have documented various Operating Systems.
http://kb.mozillazine.org/Register_protocol

Its actually trivial to register a new protocol in Windows and hook it to a executable. I have done this for some apps:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Also see
[register a protocol on mac osx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595481/register-a-protocol-on-mac-osx)